# Don't know how to return to pose mode

Tags: mesh, armature, edit-mode, pose-mode

I don't know how to return to Pose Mode. I went to Edit mode and know the Pose Mode don't appear. I've made <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: it doesn't look like you have selected an armature

Answer (score 3):

You have to select the armature to go back to pose mode, it looks like you have the mesh object selected instead.